# FreeIPA replica failed due to FIPS not being enabled on master

Tags: ldap, kerberos, freeipa

My problem is that I have a FreeIPA server master that does not have FIPS enabled and the replica that I am trying to create has FIPS enabled. When trying to install the replica on another machine it failed. FIPS need to be enabled in our environment. My questions are:

1. Can I disable FIPS in the replica and then create the replica enabling all the master roles and then turn FIPS back on? Are there any issues with this?
2. If number 1 is not possible, is there a good write up on how to backup and restore the original master to a different AWS Image, is this possible? The new image would have FIPS enabled.

@abbra

Comment: I was wondering if you could help @abbra. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no migration and there is no way to mix both FIPS-enabled and FIPS-disabled masters in the same FreeIPA deployment. You have to start from scratch.

Comment: Thanks a lot @abbra I wanted to confirm because some documentation I was reading did say that but FreeIPA documentation is lacking in many ways.